# Why isn't pandas formatting date when converting json to excel in python?

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, date

I have a JSON object like so:

```
{
    "2021-07-15": {
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value"
    },
    "2021-07-16": {
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value"
    },
    "2021-07-17": {
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value"
    }
}
```

I'm using

```
    df = pd.read_json(json_dumps)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{prefix}week_of_{start_day}-{start_month}-{start_year}.xlsx', date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd')

    df.to_excel(writer)

    writer.save()
```

in python to convert the json to an excel file.  Pandas automatically makes the dates into columns which I want, but the format still includes the time in the ensuing excel file.

Comment: Is it possible those values are a `datetime` not a `date`? Which would mean the kwarg should be `datetime_format='YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime_format='YYYY-MM-DD'` as suggested by @HenryEcker or keep the date part of your columns.

```
df.columns = df.columns.date
print(df.columns)

Index([2021-07-15, 2021-07-16, 2021-07-17], dtype='object')
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]